# How does the NSBundle's -load method register classes and other runtime resources with the Objective-C runtime?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, foundation, nsbundle, objective-c-runtime

Foundation's NSBundles are the best way to load dynamic code in Objective-C. The `-load` method dynamically loads the bundle's executable code into a running program.

But, which Objective-C runtime public function does the NSBundle's `-load` method use to load a dynamic library and register classes, categories, protocols, methods, selectors, etc, with the Objective-C runtime? In which header is it declared?

Comment: In which header is _what_ declared? Are you just asking for the list of runtime functions: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html? Or do you want details of the specific procedure that NSBundle goes through?

Comment: I'm asking for the function in the list of runtime functions that is used by the `-load` method do register the bundle's classes, methods, selectors and other resources with the obj-c runtime. Because none of those functions seem to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSBundle doesn't use the ObjC runtime for that. It uses dlopen, and the dynamic linker handles loading things.

Comment: NSBundle uses dlopen for sure, but the runtime system must keep track of the loaded classes. So, if the file contains only compiled C functions, for example, dlopen is enough. But if it contains Objective-C classes declarations, they need to be registered with the objc-runtime. How is this done?

Comment: map_images_nolock, in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-os.mm, there's no public API for this

Comment: (to be clear: dyld calls into the objc runtime, which uses that function)

Comment: Now you're talking! That's what I wanted no know. So, there is not public function for this and Cocoa must use some private Objective-C runtime headers (more specifically http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532.2/runtime/objc-private.h, which declares `map_images`) or reference `map_images` externally. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cocoa does not use this. Cocoa calls dlopen(), and *that* uses map_images.

Comment: But `dlopen()` belongs to the dynamic linking library `dlfcn.h` which is used even by non-Objective-C programs. Does `dlopen()` really call `map_images`? Or is OS X's version of this library different than the other ones and does call `map_images`? Or the `dlopen()` function we're talking about is not the one declared in `dlfcn.h`?

Comment: dyld on OSX is aware of ObjC, and can tell which images contain ObjC. Don't be fooled by it being the same header as on other platforms, the implementation is different (even for non-ObjC stuff, it still has to handle Mach-O binaries, which other platforms don't).